# Is SweetAlert2 html parameter length limited in size?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, content-plugin

I recently created a plugin for Joomla which uses the nice [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) popup script and it generally works fine. However, surprisingly, when the size of the html message I use is too long, the box does not popup and the content gets instead written to the document body itself. Is there a size limit for the html parameter or could this somehow be caused by Joomla?

- No, I did not yet isolate how many characters it fails but I will.
- No, I did not dig into SweetAlert2's code as it goes way beyond what I can do with javascript.
- Yes, I checked the miniorange plugin but it was not really what I needed.
- Here's the code for the part where I check the html parameter (note that I had to try to deal with accented characters too).

  ```
  /**
   *
   * Create content 
   * 
   * Parameters-values separators is :=
   */
  function generateText($array)
  {
      $res =explode(",",$array);

      // For each parameter
      // we extract value
      foreach ($res as  $str)
      {
          $s = explode(":=", $str);
          // Test apostrophe
          if ($s[0] == 'html' || $s[0] == 'text')
          {
              //$s[1] = trim($s[1],"'");

              if (strpos($s[1],"l'") !== false)
              {
                  $accents = str_replace("l'","l\'",$s[1]);
                  $string = "'" . $accents . "'";
              }
              else
                  $string = $s[1];
          }
          else
              $string = $s[1];

          // In case there's html, decode to keep tags
          $corr = html_entity_decode($string);
          // Add to final text
          $texte .= $s[0] . ":  " . $corr .",";
      }
      // Remove last two chars
      $new = substr($texte, 0, -1);

      return $new;
  }
  ```

`:=` is the separator and the plugin syntax is like:

```
{swal title:='<span style="font-size: 16px;">INFORMATION</span>',html:='<span style="font-size: 14px;">Mask and sanitary pass are</span><b><span style="font-size: 14px; color: #FF0000;"> mandatory for all adults and kids from 12 to 17 to....</span></b><br /><br /><b>Thanks!</b>',icon:='info',confirmButtonText:='OK',iconColor:='#FF0000'}{/swal}
```

Comment: Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.  Did you dig into the code yourself to hunt for clues? Did you isolate how many characters are required to trigger the bug? Did you know about https://plugins.miniorange.com/joomla-sweet-alert before creating your own plugin?  May we see the vital parts of your custom plugin? What html element receives the excessively long text?  Please [edit] your question is you can provide any of these details.

Comment: Honestly, there isn't much worth keeping in your snippet.  I don't mean to be rude, but there is much to fix and refine.  Please show me a few examples of examples of input strings and your exact desire return value for each input.  This way I can craft something a bit more professional for you.

Comment: A variable called `$array` should never contain string-type data.

Comment: Without being able to test, I'd say that `$string = "'" . $accents . "'";` will be breaking the SweetAlert's parsing code.  I assume that it is looking for single-quote wrapped substrings, but you are mangling the substrings whenever `l'` is found.  Is this the goal: https://3v4l.org/QiGci ?

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for helping out. Forgot to say that php is not my main skill as you figured...Yes, your sample is probably what I need. I'll try to see what happens and I'll also probably stay away from php in the future :)

Comment: We all have different strengths and weaknesses -- there's nothing to be ashamed of or avoid.  We all grow when we all share our knowledge.

Comment: I hope this question will not be abandoned.  Please continue to progress this question so that an acceptable answer can be posted (by someone).